# React native App isn't working on IOS simulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

My app is working fine on the Android simulator without any issues but when I am trying to do it on IOS then I am getting errors mentioned below.

```
 WARN  The "UMNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that @unimodules/react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly
 WARN  No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?
 WARN  Require cycle: src/services/profile/ProfileNetworkService.ts -> src/services/NetworkService.ts -> src/services/profile/ProfileNetworkService.ts

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Did you install 3rd party native package?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Like example? I have installed also done pod install in the ios folder.

Comment: try to run `npx react-native-clean-project clean-project-auto` on project folder

Comment: @HarshMishra package name?

Comment: @B.Mohammad I have tried this Xcode->Profuct->Clean Build. But still, I am getting same error.

Comment: try `pod deintegrate  &&  pod install`.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Actually, I have not added any package in recent although I was working only on android so I started working on ios just now and got these errors. Also, I have to rebuild the ios folder. By just init new project and copy its ios folder in my old project with the same name. Should I paste my package.json too?